# How can I pass a member function from a derived class as a callback?

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

I have a simple class `X`

```
class X {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void doSomething(T &completion) {
        std::cout << completion(10) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and a class `A` and `B`

```
class A {
public: 
 // some code
 X* c;
};

class B : public A {
public:
  int test(int x) {
    return x * x;
  }

  void execute() {
   auto lambda = [] (int x) { cout << x * 50 << endl; return x * 100; };
   c->doSomething(lambda); // works
   c->doSomething(&B::test); // does not work
  }
};
```

I want to pass to the `doSomething` method a member method of class `B` (or any other class derived from `A`) but it just does not work :/

Comment: `test` is not a function. it is a class method. There's a big difference. The template attempts to call a class method as if it was a function. That's not going to work. You need a class instance to call a class method. Where's the instance of the class whose method you are planning to call?

Comment: @JeJo yes, my mistake ;) Edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I pass a member function from a derived class as a callback?

Your problem has nothing to do with `B` being a child class. Your problem is that you're not *binding* the *non-static member function* `test()` to its instance.

You can address this easily, either by [using `std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to return a *functor*:

```
c->doSomething(std::bind(&B::test, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

and don't forget to `#include <functional>`,

or use a *lambda* to wrap the call by putting `this` in the [lambda *captures*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
c->doSomething([this](int x){ return this->test(x); });
```

Note: Make sure to change `doSomething()`'s parameter to be a *rvalue reference* so it could properly take all this callback goodness in both temporary objects and otherwise. Should look like this:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T&& completion)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!
Note: I had to remove the `&` from the `doSomething` method

Comment: Or better yet add a 2nd `&` : ) Sorry I missed it in your code. Will edit it in. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Make `B::test` a static method and it will work as written:

```
static int test(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
// ...
c->doSomething(&B::test);
```

This is because a static method doesn't require an implicit instance (a `this` pointer).

If `B::test` must be a regular method, then you must pass the instance by using a capturing lambda, like this:

```
c->doSomething([this] (int x) { return this->test(x); });
```

**NOTE:**  when getting this code to compile, I needed to change your definition of `doSomething` to leave the `&` off of `T`:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T completion) {
    std::cout << completion(10) << std::endl;
}
```

This prevents putting a l-value, or non-const, constraint on the function pointer type, which can prevent the compiler from creating a temporary lambda function.

Comment: Thanks! The `Note` part was very helpfull! It works now as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `c->doSomething([this](int x) { return this->test(x); });` ?

Comment: Yes this was it, but it should be `doSomething` instead of `test`